# Find passphrase using private key

Tags: go-ethereum, private-key

I have a wallet's private key. Can I find the secret phrase/backup phrase through it?

Can I also find out what the other wallets in the wallet sequence would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can derive a wallet private key from it's mnemonic phrase but you can not find mnemonic from a wallet private key
- it's a key structure. each mnemonic gives you lots of addresses in different coins

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Suppose I have a wallet address. Can I also find the other wallets in the sequence even if I don't have the mnemonics?

Comment: no it's a one way road from mnemonic to wallets:
imagine you want Ethereum wallet :
wallet in index 0 is accessible in m/44'/0'/0'/0
wallet in index 1 is accessible in m/44'/0'/0'/1
This link will give you a better understanding
https://iancoleman.io/bip39/

Comment: Great! Thanks for your comment.